# Is it a good practice to inherit a generic class from a non generic class, in Java?

Tags: java, generics, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have this code:

```
public abstract class Course<T extends Student> {
    private String name;
    private int months;
    private int capacity;
    private static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public Course(String name, int months, int capacity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.months= months;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(students);
    }

    protected void addStudent(Student student){
        students.add(student);
    }

    public abstract void enroll(T student);
}

public class Math extends Course<Student> {

    public Math(String name, int months, int capacity) {
        super(name, months, capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public void enroll(Student student) {
        System.out.println(student.getClass());
        if (student instanceof MathBackground) {
            if (this.getCapacity() <= this.getStudents().size()) {
                System.out.println("The course is already full. We will add you to the waitlist");
            } else {
                this.addStudent(student);
                System.out.println("The student " + student.getName() + " has been enrolled");
            }
        } else{
            System.out.println("Can not enroll the student " + student.getName() + " due to the background");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have a more than one subclass for the Course and I'm trying to make it as generic as possible, so I can add another course called "Economics" for example, in which I'll make its own enrol process.

More details:

- I have a `List<Student>` which contains more types of Students, from `MathStudent` to `BiologyStudent` and so on..
- I'd like for the Math class to have something that could only let the students that implement the `MathBackground` interface join, probably my approach is not very good since I understood that it is not a good practice to extend a generic class from a non generic.

I also want to ask, is it a better approach to have the type as the parent type? I mean, should I have:

```
Course mathClass = new Math();
```

or

```
Math mathClass = new Math();
```

Comment: Why does `Math` extend `Course<Student>` instead of `Course<MathStudent>`? Why does `Course.getStudents()` not return `List<T>`?

Comment: Please show more about how you want to use the `Math` class.

Comment: I don't want to extend the MathStudent because then it will make the Math class only workable for the math students, but I'd like to add more type of students.

For example I have:
Student student1 = new MathStudent("Name", etc...);
Student student2 = new EconomyStudent("Name", etc...);
Student student3 = new BiologyStudent("Name", etc...);

If I extend Course<MathStudent> then I won't be abble to add the EconomyStudent to it. So in other words I'd like a Math class that would take in all the students that implement the MathBackground (MathStudent and EconomyStudent implement it)

Comment: And with all the courses that I ll get, I want to make a course catalog that will contain every course for every user

Comment: Why does `Course` need to be parameterized by `Student`? This makes no sense, especially since you don't use `T` in the code.  It is unclear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's any point in having `Course` be generic -- if every subclass will extend `Course<Student>`.

Comment: To answer the question in your title, all Generic classes in Java ultimately inherit from `java.lang.Object`, so there is nothing inherently wrong with the practice; but your class hierarchy looks upside down and back to front.

Comment: @JimGarrison it doesn’t need, it’s not mandatory, I mean I thought that by parameterizing the course by the student in the end I ll create a Math object that will only take some kind of Students

Comment: The model you seem to want doesn't really work.  Courses and Students are different types of objects, with the only relationship being a third type of object (a CourseRegistration).  If you restrict courses to specific student types at the source code level your system will be impossible to maintain and enhance as requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind one type of object to another type without adding restrictions to each of the type .You could employ enum which will give compile time error if you fail to define coupling.

We added abstract method in Course so that we are defining coupling while creating new course.

```
public abstract CourseStudentPair getCourseStudentPair();
```

We could easily extend the functionality to allow multiple student type for a course using varargs as below later.Following [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) defined one to one coupling for now.

```
    CourseStudentPair(Class courseClass, Class ... studentClass)
```

Since we want to check the student type while enrolling only, we could implement it as

```
    if ( !getCourseStudentPair().isValidStudForCourse(student, course))
```

the complete snippet

```
@Data
public abstract class Course<T extends Student> {
    private String name;
    private int months;
    private int capacity;
    private static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public Course(String name, int months, int capacity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.months= months;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(students);
    }

    protected void addStudent(Student student){
        students.add(student);
    }

    public abstract void enroll(T student);
    public abstract CourseStudentPair getCourseStudentPair();

}

class Math extends Course<Student> {

    public Math(String name, int months, int capacity) {
        super(name, months, capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public void enroll(Student student) {
        System.out.println(student.getClass());
        if ( !getCourseStudentPair().isValidStudForCourse(student, this)) {
            System.out.println("Can not enroll the student " + student.getName() + " due to the background");
        }

        if (this.getCapacity() <= this.getStudents().size()) {
            System.out.println("The course is already full. We will add you to the waitlist");
        } else {
            this.addStudent(student);
            System.out.println("The student " + student.getName() + " has been enrolled");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CourseStudentPair getCourseStudentPair() {
        return CourseStudentPair.MATH;
    }
}

enum CourseStudentPair {
    MATH(Math.class,MathStudent.class),ECONOMICS(Economics.class,EconomicsStudent.class);

    private final Class courseClass;
    private final Class studentClass;

    CourseStudentPair(Class courseClass, Class studentClass) {
        this.courseClass = courseClass;
        this.studentClass = studentClass;
    }

    public boolean isValidStudForCourse(@NonNull Student student, @NonNull Course course){
        return  studentClass.isInstance(student) && courseClass.isInstance(course)  ;
    }

}
```